# Change color and sku at the same time in magento simple configurable product

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I am using colour select plus extension. I want to change SKU of selected product at the same time it swatches its colour. now i am using the function to change SKU. when i call that function colour swatches stops to work. 
php:

```
<div class="input-box">
                    <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attributeId ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $attributeId ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select<?php if($hide == 1) echo ' swatchSelect' ?>" onchange="return changeSku(<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>, this), 300);">
                        <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                    </select>
                    </div>




    function changeSku(confAttributeId, sel){

    var productMap = <?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($productMap);?>;
        var selectedAttributeId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedAttributeId) {
            var options = spConfig.config.attributes[confAttributeId].options;
            var productId = options.find(function (option) {return option.id == selectedAttributeId}).products[0]
            $("sku-container").update("<strong><div style='color:red'>Product SKU: </strong>" + productMap[productId])+ "</div>";
        } else {
            $("sku-container").update("<strong><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?>");
        }

}
```

Comment: provide some code to explain your problem

Comment: please help me i unable to do with above code